# DNN 9 Module only displays in Edit Mode

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

We recently upgraded an old DNN site to the latest version (9.8.00).  Everything has been running fine for the most part, but today I have ran into an issue I can't figure out how to resolve.  Once of my users dropped an HTML module on the page but we can not get it to display outside of edit mode.  I have tried adding an HTML module to other pages as well to see if it was isolated to an individual page, but it's doing the same thing across the entire site.  I have tried all of the following things to no avail.

- Debugged the page to make sure no errors where being thrown and none are.
- Stopped inheriting permissions and made the module visible to all users.
- Changed the Cache settings for the module to 0.
- Verified the site was running on .Net 4.5.1 (I'm actually on 4.7.1).
- Tested two other modules (link and event), both of these modules display outside of edit mode.

I am at a loss at this point.  The HTML module is showing as version 9.8.0, but has an upgrade version as 10.0.3.  So I'm not sure if that means it needs to be upgraded or it has already been upgraded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but a few recommendations. Assuming you've got easy backup and restore capabilities, do the upgrade to DNN 9.08.01 (do not go to 9.09.00 at this time). Also, if you are correct about .NET 4.7.1, I would upgrade further, to at least 4.7.2 and better go all the way to 4.8.latest. The only other thing I can think to suggest testing is to try switch themes. Switch back to the default Xcillion theme (both for the page skin and the container). If still nothing works, you may have to wait for DNN 9.09.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recents versions of the HTML module have this behaviour: they doesn't appear when they haven't any content. After you add some content, they keep displayed.
I think this feature is related to the default template which is containing an empty HTML module.